# Assistance with complex MySQL query (using LIMIT ?)

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

I wonder if anyone could help with a MySQL query I am trying to write to return relevant results.

I have a big table of change log data, and I want to retrieve a number of record 'groups'.  For example, in this case a group would be where two or more records are entered with the same timestamp.

Here is a sample table.

```
==============================================
ID     DATA                         TIMESTAMP
==============================================
1      Some text                    1379000000
2      Something                    1379011111
3      More data                    1379011111
3      Interesting data             1379022222
3      Fascinating text             1379033333
```

If I wanted the first two grouped sets, I could use `LIMIT 0,2` but this would miss the third record. The ideal query would return three rows (as two rows have the same timestamp).

```
==============================================
ID     DATA                         TIMESTAMP
==============================================
1      Some text                    1379000000
2      Something                    1379011111
3      More data                    1379011111
```

Currently I've been using PHP to process the entire table, which mostly works, but for a table of 1000+ records, this is not very efficient on memory usage!

Many thanks in advance for any help you can give...

Comment: How does the query know that ID =1 gets included with ID In (2,3)? It has a different timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the timestamps for the filtering using a `join`.  For instance, the following would make sure that the second timestamp is in a completed group:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select timestamp
      from t
      order by timestamp
      limit 2
     ) tt
     on t.timestamp = tt.timestamp;
```

The following would get the first three groups, no matter what their size:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select distinct timestamp
      from t
      order by timestamp
      limit 3
     ) tt
     on t.timestamp = tt.timestamp;
```

Comment: This is great, works really well!  To help me understand the code for future use, could I ask what the `tt` relates to (on the last two lines)?

Comment: @user2761030 . . . `tt` is a table alias.  That is an abbreviation for a table that can then be used throughout the query (as you see in the `on` clause).  They are needed when the same table appears multiple times in the `from` clause.  They are otherwise desirable because they can make queries easier to read.

Comment: @user2761030 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a39db/2 here you can see what it does (what data it returns to make it more visible)  note you should really also index timestamp without index timestamp http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb0f0/1  mysql needs also un extra sort and more full table scans are needed